# SMS Alphanumeric Sender Id Encoding

Tags: sms, gsm, sim800

When I receive sms on my sim808 module, i can see it as

```
AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"

+CMGL: 21,"REC UNREAD","+919538634187","","18/01/28,13:20:31+22"
test1455

OK
```

When I send the message using a service that uses alphanumeric sender id, I get this

```
AT+CMGL="REC UNREAD"

+CMGL: 21,"REC UNREAD","14w4w2#45444147425","","18/01/28,13:20:31+22"
test1455

OK
```

I would like to know how can I decode `14w4w2#45444147425` to get the alphanumeric sender id?